# Class active for Archive link - looped out

Tags: categories, loop, menus, links

I want to have the current Archive page link to have the class "selected". So if I'm in /category/featured/ that button on the menu should have the class selected.
After trying several different ways all im managing to do is make all the archive links have the class if Im in any of those. How can i make it so it only targets one ?

When /category/featured/ is active the rest should not have class selected..

So i have all my categories looped out so:

```
<?php $categories = get_categories(); ?>

 

<?php  foreach($categories as $category) {
   
   echo '<a class="'. (( is_archive()?'selected"':"")) .'" href="'. get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->name . '</a>';
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to get the current object ID with [`get_queried_object_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/) and compare it against the category term ID inside the foreach loop. E.g.

```
$current_object_id = get_queried_object_id();

foreach (get_categories() as $category) {

  $classes = '';
  if ( $category->term_id === $current_object_id ) {
    $classes .= 'selected';
  }

  printf(
    '<a class="%s" href="%s">%s</a>',
    $classes,
    get_category_link($category->term_id),
    $category->name
  );
}
```

[`is_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/) should work too as it is basically a fancy wrapper for the same check as above.

```
foreach (get_categories() as $category) {

  $classes = '';
  // Parameter can be category ID, name, slug, or array of such
  if ( is_category( $category->term_id ) ) {
    $classes .= 'selected';
  }

  printf(
    '<a class="%s" href="%s">%s</a>',
    $classes,
    get_category_link($category->term_id),
    $category->name
  );
}
```